# Using Floating Point with GCC Inline Assembler

Tags: floating-point, return-value, inline-assembly, return-value-optimization

I am writing some debug macros, and one of the macros is to capture the return value of a function when the return value is not assigned to a variable. This may be useful in cases where the return value is useful in debugging but is not needed in the release version.

The following macro works with both integral and pointer types:

```
#define DebugReturn(TYPE,fcn) \
    int fcn##_return; \
    __asm("movl %%eax,%0":"=mr"(fcn##_return)); \
    TYPE fcn##_returned = (TYPE) fcn##_return
```

For example:

```
static int Foobar( int &x, int &y )
{
    x = 7;
    y = 8;
    return 9;
}

Foobar( x, y );
DebugReturn( int, Foobar );
DebugTraceFunction( "Foobar( x, y );", x, y, Foobar_returned );
```

will correctly display the return value of 9.

I've tried variations of the following macro with floating-point types, but none of them work:

```
#define DebugReturnFloatingPoint(fcn) \
    double register fcn##_return; \
    float fcn##_returned = 2.718281828; \
    __asm("fstl %0":"=m"(fcn##_returned):"t"(fcn##_return))
```

For example:

```
static float FOOBAR( int x, int y )
{
    return 3.14159;
}

FOOBAR( x, y );
DebugReturnFloatingPoint( FOOBAR );
DebugTraceFunction( "FOOBAR( x, y );", x, y, FOOBAR_returned );
```

always displays a return value of 3.0056636E+33, regardless of what value FOOBAR actually returns. If I remove the line double register fcn##_return; and the input parameter :"t"(fcn##_return), it always displays a return value of zero. The reason for the inital value of 2.718281828 is to check that the value is actually modified by the assembly instruction. I'm not concerned with the precision of the result.

Of course, I could easily write float FOOBAR_returned = FOOBAR( x, y ), but the reason for doing it with a macro is to make it easy to clean up the code in the final build. The macros will be defined to empty strings in the release version, but in the final build I want to delete them entirely and not have any unreferenced local variables.

So what is wrong with my floating-point instruction?

Comment: Have you examined the output from -S?  My guess would be that on return from FOOBAR, gcc always has to clear the floating point stack.  It either moves it into a variable, or simply discards it.  By the time you get to the asm, the value is already gone.

Comment: @david I put the code into a small program to test it:

Comment: @david I put the code into a small program to test it and built it using g++ testprog.cpp -o testprog and the same problem occurred.

So I built it using g++ testprog -S but it causes gcc to hang up. I tried it a couple of times, and each time after 20 minutes it was still hung up. The output file only contained

 .file ""

What would cause gcc to hang up?

Comment: How about `g++ -S testprog.cpp`?

Comment: @david As you can probably tell, I'm relatively new to gcc; I'm accustomed to using Microsoft Visual Studio.

I tried g++ -S testprog.cpp, but it hung up for 12 hours before I stopped it. I did some reasearch and found I could use objdump to get the disassembly, and here is what I got:

    call   401190 <__ZL6FOOBARii>
    fstp   %st(0)
    mov    0x4020d4,%eax
    mov    %eax,0x2c(%esp)
    fldl   0x30(%esp)
    fstl   0x2c(%esp)

So it pops the stack immediately after the function call, but where does it put the value?

Comment: (continued) The operand %st(0) makes no sense in that context. When you pop the floating point stack, the value has to be stored in memory, but the operand looks like a floating point register.

Comment: Actually, it /doesn't/ have to be a memory location (check the docs for fstp). It is, effectively, storing the value right back where it already was. AND popping the stack (the 'p' part of fstp). This makes sense since the ABI would require that /somebody/ clean up the fp stack.  Which means reading the value with asm like that won't work.  How about something like `#define FOOBAR(a, b)  ( { float f = foobar(a, b); DumpReturn(f); f; })`?  Not ISO standard, but gcc allows it (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).

Comment: Also, 12 hours is ridiculous.  It shouldn't take any longer to compile with -S than it does without (presumably a few seconds).

Comment: Okay, so what I'm trying to do won't work with floating point. Thanks for the help!